# Is there a way to override a Perl "use constant" in your unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, perl, mocking, constants, compile-time-constant

I have a Perl module that I have declared some constants:

```
use constant BASE_PATH => "/data/monitor/";
```

In live operation the constant will **never** change but I wish to be able to modify it in my unit tests, e.g. to set it to `~/project/testdata/`.  Is there a way do do this without having to use global mutable variables?

Could I possibly use `Test::MockObject` on the `constant`?

Comment: If you need to change it throughout the tests why wouldn't u make it a 'non-constant'

Comment: You could try monkey patching constant's import subroutine.

Comment: Why would you do this instead of having a config file?

Comment: I find myself in this same position. Please see my solution: 10 years late to the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58920320/124486 Consider marking it as chosen if it's the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using constants they are implemented as constant functions behaving something like:

```
use subs 'BASE_PATH';
sub BASE_PATH () {"/data/monitor/"}
```

Any uses of BASE_PATH in the program are inlined and so can't be modified.

To achieve similar you could manually use the subs pragma (to make BASE_PATH behave as a built in function) and declare BASE_PATH as a standard function:

```
use subs 'BASE_PATH';
sub BASE_PATH {"/data/monitor/"}

print "BASE_PATH is ".BASE_PATH."\n";

*BASE_PATH = sub {"/new/path"};
print "BASE_PATH is ".BASE_PATH."\n";
```

Although why you would want to do this I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 5):

Tests often reveal inflexibility in the design.  This is one of those times.  That constant shouldn't be constant.

If you're doing it for performance reasons I'm willing to bet hard currency that it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I think it's useful to communicate to developers the constant won't change in the execution of the program, and to still allow testers to change this. This is pretty common. For example in C you could set a constant with custom logic using the preprocessor. I don't see it about preoptimization. He wants to say the base path is immutable and can't change, unless he wants to change it in a testing environment.

Comment: @EvanCarroll It's really more about the inflexibly. If you need to change it in testing, you'll probably have other reasons; especially a path. To communicate its purpose wrap it in a configuration object. It can start as a simple wrapper around a hash and  build on that:  read from a config file, environment variables, or selecting the proper values for dev, testing, and production.

Answer (score 3):

```
package My::Class;

use constant BASE_PATH => "/a/real/value/";

# ..more code here..

1;
```

Now in your unit tests:

```
use My::Class;
*{My::Class::BASE_PATH} = sub { "/a/fake/value" };

# do your tests here...
```

Comment: Would this work with subs in a module?
For example:
``use myModule;
*{myModule} = sub { "/a/fake/value" };``

If not then is there a way to do this?

Comment: @GuySoft see my answer

Comment: @EvanCarroll My question was about subs in a module, can't see that in the unconstant docs. Also at the time I was editing code I could not really edit. Anyway this was 6 years ago and I have no access to that codebase

Comment: @GuySoft well just to answer that question directly then, subs in a module can be redefined in perl from any package using the syntax provided by Ether. That is unless those subs are inlined. Then at the point you redefine them it's too late. Some modules like `constant` produce subs that get inlined. For those you need a little bit more, like `unconstant`.

Answer (score 3):

## [`unconstant`](https://metacpan.org/pod/unconstant)

One easy method to do this is to use `unconstant`.

```
# From ./lib/Foo.pm
package Foo {
    use constant BASE_PATH => '/data/monitor/';
}


# From test.pl
use unconstant;  # Do this first
use Foo;
use constant *Foo::BASE_PATH => '/otherData/otherMonitor/';
```

---

Disclaimer: *I am the author of `unconstant`, but I had this very same issue.*

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, if your definition of BASE_PATH was used/compiled into another subroutine BEFORE your test does change it (via

```
*BASE_PATH = sub { ... }
```

or other stuff) you have no solution (because when the original module used BASE_PATH as a constant, it really defined an INLINE function that was, well, inlined when used in other code)

Comment: The only solution is to monkey patch constant's import subroutine. Install a wrapper around constant's import that intercepts specified constant names to be overridden and the values to apply.  If you do this, then only the overriden constant subs will be created and they will be inlined by the compiler.  I don't have time to write something like this right now, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: But in that case, making your own constant.pm that does not let the sub be inlined would be even better/easier, no? put it somewhere early in the test library path and ta-da...

Comment: You can stop the inlining. See my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58920320/124486/